# C# - Insert first colum from text file to database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I would like to read from text file and insert his first column as row in database.

This is the text file how it looks like:

```
1264311 | SMS_DR | DELIVERED
 373414 | SMS_DR | EXPIRED
    418 | SMS_DR | UNDELIVERABLE
1628984 | SMS_MT |
```

I want to get only the first column with integer values and insert them in my database as a row to have this:

```
DELIVERED   EXPIRED     UNDELIVERABLE       BLABLA
1264311     373414      418                 1628984
```

When i run my code it inserts all 4 lines, this my code:

```
sr1 = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\adamoui\\Desktop\\Statjbm_20161009.txt");

string[] allLines1 = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\adamoui\\Desktop\\Statjbm_20161009.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < allLines1.Length; i++)
{                
    string[] column = allLines1[i].Split(new char[] { '|' });
    SqlCommand cmdJBM = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.StatJBM_NEW (Noeud, Total_MT, Date, DELIVERED, EXPIRED, UNDELIVERABLE) VALUES (@Noeud, @Total_MT, @Date, @DELIVERED, @EXPIRED, @UNDELIVERABLE)", con);
    cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Noeud", "JBM");
    cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELIVERED", column[0]);
    cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRED", column[0]);
    cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNDELIVERABLE", column[0]);
    cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_MT", column[0]);
    cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
    cmdJBM.ExecuteNonQuery();                
}
con.Close();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: do you know how many lines your file will have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something of this sort:

```
var delivered = allLines[0].Split(new char[] { '|' })[0];
var expired = allLines[1].Split(new char[] { '|' })[0];
var undeliverable = allLines[2].Split(new char[] { '|' })[0];
....
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELIVERED", delivered);
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRED", expired);
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNDELIVERABLE", undeliverable);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is what i need!

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes an insert for each line, using the first column as all params. Probably not what you had in mind. Try this:

```
var values = allLines1.Split('|')
                      .Select(arr => arr[0])
                      .ToArray();

SqlCommand cmdJBM = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO dbo.StatJBM_NEW
                                    (Noeud, Total_MT, Date, DELIVERED, EXPIRED,
                                    UNDELIVERABLE) VALUES (@Noeud, @Total_MT, @Date,
                                    @DELIVERED, @EXPIRED, @UNDELIVERABLE)", con);
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Noeud", "JBM");
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELIVERED", values[0]);
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRED", values[1]);
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNDELIVERABLE", values[2]);
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_MT", values[3]);
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
cmdJBM.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the loop and do something like this:

```
cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELIVERED", allLines1[0].Split(new char[] { '|' })[0]);
```

If you know the indexes and exact number of rows that your file will have, you can just put the indexes right into your code.

Answer (score 1):

U have logical mistake... In your column array are the splits of the current line.

But why you create sr1 = new StreamReader and don't use it ?

File.ReadAllLines is a quick version for small files...but for big Files you can get a OutOfMemoryException.

Try this.

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        //current line from the file
        string line;

        //filereader
        using (var file = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\adamoui\\Desktop\\Statjbm_20161009.txt"))
        {
            //list for the first columns
            var firstColumnInFile = new List<string>();

            //read every line 
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //split line
                var items = line.Split('|');
                // add the first column in the list;
                firstColumnInFile.Add(items.First());
            }

            if(firstColumnInFile.Count < 4)
                return;

            SqlCommand cmdJBM = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO dbo.StatJBM_NEW
                                (Noeud, Total_MT, Date, DELIVERED, EXPIRED,
                                UNDELIVERABLE) VALUES (@Noeud, @Total_MT, @Date,
                                @DELIVERED, @EXPIRED, @UNDELIVERABLE)", con);
            cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Noeud", "JBM");
            cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELIVERED", firstColumnInFile[0]); //first column
            cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRED", firstColumnInFile[1]); //second column
            cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNDELIVERABLE", firstColumnInFile[2]); //third column
            cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_MT", firstColumnInFile[3]); //...
            cmdJBM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all opening file with `StreamReader` and then read content with `File.ReadAllLines()` is useless (and you keep file in use because you do not dispose `StreamReader`.)

Assuming that file is well-formed (and not huge to use all process memory) then first read its content:

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\adamoui\Desktop\Statjbm_20161009.txt");
```

Then strip unwanted fields (just two tokens, we don't need to create 2X strings we do not use):

```
var allValues = allLines.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '|' }, 2)[0]);
```

Now you need to group lines 4-by-4. I'd first introduce an helper function you may reuse elsewhere (no error checking here):

```
static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count, int step) {
    for (int i=0; i < count; i += step)
        yield return start + i;
}
```

Now we can loop through our values as required:

```
var records = Range(0, allValues.Length, 4).Select(x => {
    return new {
        Delivered = allValues[x + 0],
        Expired = allValues[x + 1],
        // ...
    };
});
```

Let's also introduce some constants to clean your code:

```
const string InsertRecordCommand = "INSERT INTO dbo.StatJBM_NEW (Noeud, Total_MT, Date, DELIVERED, EXPIRED, UNDELIVERABLE) VALUES (@Noeud, @Total_MT, @Date, @DELIVERED, @EXPIRED, @UNDELIVERABLE)";
```

---

To put everything together (also disposing disposable objects where required):

```
var allValues = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\adamoui\Desktop\Statjbm_20161009.txt")
    .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '|' }, 2)[0])
    .ToArray();

var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var records = Range(0, allValues.Length, 4).Select(x => {
    return new {
        Noeud = "JBM",
        Delivered = allValues[x + 0],
        Expired = allValues[x + 1],
        Undeliverable = allValues[x + 2],
        TotalMt = allValeus[x + 3],
        Date = yesterday
    };
});

foreach (var record in records)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(InsertRecordCommand , con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Noeud", record.Noeud);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELIVERED", record.Delivered);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRED", record.Expired);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNDELIVERABLE", record.Undeliverable);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_MT", record.TotalMt);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", record.Date);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
    }
}
```

Now maybe it's time to simplify your code. You may want to use a lightweight mapper like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net):

```
var allValues = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\adamoui\Desktop\Statjbm_20161009.txt")
    .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '|' }, 2)[0])
    .ToArray();

var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
con.Insert(Range(0, allValues.Length, 4).Select(x => {
    return new {
        Noeud = "JBM",
        Delivered = allValues[x + 0],
        Expired = allValues[x + 1],
        Undeliverable = allValues[x + 2],
        Total_Mt = allValeus[x + 3],
        Date = yesterday
    };
}));
```

That's all (I do not mention to do not hardcode paths and to use `Environment.GetFolder()` because I guess this is just an example.) Please consult Dapper documentation for further details about its configuration and conventions, note that without contribs it may also be like this:

```
foreach (var record in records)
    con.Execute(InsertRecordCommand, record);
```